# Bundling my CSS files inside my ASP.NET MVC core web application is raising "Unexpected token" Error

Tags: css, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, bundle, bundling-and-minification

I have a css file which start with this code:-

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700&display=swap");
/* line 1, ../../Arafath/CL/Cl November/223. Transportation/HTML/scss/_extend.scss */
.flex-center-start {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  justify-content: start;
}
```

But if I bundle this css file, I am getting this error:-

```
Unexpected token, found 'url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700&display=swap")'  
Unexpected token, found 'url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700&display=swap")'
```

Now if I remove this code.

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700&display=swap");
```

the error will gone, but not sure why i am getting this error?